# Why can't I "star" the PhoneGap tag, but I can for ALL others?

Tags: cordova

When I hover over the PhoneGap tag and try and click the "star" to make PhoneGap one of my favorites, it doesn't work. All other tags work like normal though...

Also, when I try and add the PhoneGap tag, as soon as I click Save, it disappears like I never added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the right place for this question, should be on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  Regardless though, it's because the PhoneGap tag is a synonym for Cordova.  So everything in PhoneGap is Cordova.